# Trigger text cursor programmatically like user actually clicked input tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, input, click

I'm trying to input some value into text field using javascript like Gmail email input tag.
But the problem happened with some of the fancy animations for their placeholder bind to some events that I don't know how to trigger, like images show below:

Input tag without focus/select:
￼[image: Input tag without focus/select]
Input after input something there:
[image: Input after input something there]
Input tag with focus/select:
[image: Input tag with focus/select]

Then after I assigned the value, my value and the fancy placeholder will overlap each other.

I tried multiple ways, focus/select/click/both, nothing works. So I'm thinking if I can trigger that animation like user actually click it then assign the value to it may work.

How can I achieve this? or is there any other way to let that animation or their input check code capture my assigned value, so after that placeholder won't come down and overlap my value?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you built you input, so there might be an easier way to handle it.
Because I personally use [JQuery](http://jquery.com/) I would do it with the [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) function.

```
$(element).toggle();
```

You can also change the css attributes with the [.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/) function. Just create an on focus event and change the color etc in there.

Hope that was there you asked for.
Good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `focus` and `focusout` from jQuery and toggle the classes with `removeClass` and `addClass`.

For example, you can do it like this :

```
$("input").focus(function(){
  $(this).parent().addClass("is-active is-completed");
});

$("input").focusout(function(){
  if($(this).val() === "")
    $(this).parent().removeClass("is-completed");
  $(this).parent().removeClass("is-active");
})
```

You can also use the [materialize css's input](http://materializecss.com/forms.html).